# Passing return value to setsockopts() caller if copy_to_user() fails?

Tags: linux-kernel, sockets, netfilter

I'm registering new setsockopts() commands with `nf_register_sockopt()`:

```
static struct nf_sockopt_ops my_sockopts = {
    list:       {NULL, NULL},
    pf:         PF_INET,
    set_optmin: MY_OPT_MIN,
    set_optmax: MY_OPT_MAX,
    set:        my_set_so,
    get_optmin: 0,
    get_optmax: 0,
    get:        NULL
};

nf_register_sockopt(&my_sockopts);
```

I want to return an error code from the (kernel-space) function `my_set_so()` back to the user space. So, I copy this code with `copy_to_user()`:

```
int my_set_so(struct sock *sk, int cmd, void *param, unsigned int len) {
  struct my_so_param user_data;
  user_data.return_value = do_my_kernelspace_work();
  if (copy_to_user(param, &user_data, sizeof(user_data)))
    HOW TO INDICATE THE FAILURE HERE?
}
```

I understand that `setsockopt()`, according to the manual page, will return some system error code in case if socket-level error happens. If the error appears in the command handling code, `setsockopt()` still returns 0, and the return value must be checked from the `void*` parameter.

Is this understanding correct? If yes, how should the (userspace) caller be informed about failure of `copy_to_user()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question right you have to return `-EFAULT` which accordingly to manual page means

> EFAULT
>   The address pointed to by optval is not in a valid part of the process address space. For getsockopt(), this error may also be returned if optlen is not in a valid part of the process address space.

So,

```
int my_set_so(struct sock *sk, int cmd, void *param, unsigned int len) {
  struct my_so_param user_data;
  user_data.return_value = do_my_kernelspace_work();
  if (copy_to_user(param, &user_data, sizeof(user_data)))
    return -EFAULT; /* HOW TO INDICATE THE FAILURE HERE? */
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not see how this answer is consistent with the manual pages. The latter instruct to return -1 on error, not -EFAULT (and, besides returning -1, also set errno to the appropriate value).

Comment: Are we talking about user space or kernel space? FYI: there is no `errno` in kernel space.